# Making a Tkinter calculator that gives back percent at a given point in a interval

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Hi I'm getting a 'float' object is not callable error while running this code. I'm using python 2.7.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import math
sys.argv=["Main"]
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *


def CalcRpmRatio():
    rpmMax = rpmMaxSet.get
    rpmMin = rpmMinSet.get
    rpmPoint = rpmPointSet.get
    newrpmMax = rpmMax() - rpmMin()
    result = rpmPoint() / newrpmMax()
    showResult = Label (mGui, text=str(ResultCount)+". "+str(result)).pack()
    global ResultCount
    ResultCount +=1

    return

ResultCount = 1
mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('400x150+200+200')
mGui.title('RPM To Percent Calc')
rpmMaxSet = DoubleVar()
rpmMinSet = DoubleVar()
rpmPointSet = DoubleVar()
rpmMaxSetLabel = Label(mGui, text='Max RPM').pack()
rpmMaxSetEntry = Entry(textvariable=rpmMaxSet) .pack()
rpmMinSetLabel = Label(mGui, text='Min RPM').pack()
rpmMinSetEntry = Entry(textvariable=rpmMinSet) .pack()
rpmMinPointLabel = Label(mGui, text='Point RPM').pack()
rpmPointSetEntry = Entry(textvariable=rpmPointSet) .pack()

mButton = Button(mGui, text='Calculate', command = CalcRpmRatio, fg = 'white', bg='black').pack()
mGui.mainloop()
```

I'm new to python so there might be a obvious answer to this.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. `newrpmMax()` this line is the problem. your `newrpmMax` is float and you can't call it. just use it as it is. `result = rpmPoint() / newrpmMax`

Comment: Thank you! Stackoverflow is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update the follwing lines**

```
rpmMax = rpmMaxSet.get()
rpmMin = rpmMinSet.get()
rpmPoint = rpmPointSet.get()
newrpmMax = rpmMax- rpmMin
result = rpmPoint / newrpmMax
```

Here is the edited version I tried it and it works

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import math
sys.argv=["Main"]
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *


def CalcRpmRatio():
    rpmMax = rpmMaxSet.get()
    rpmMin = rpmMinSet.get()
    rpmPoint = rpmPointSet.get()
    newrpmMax = rpmMax- rpmMin
    result = rpmPoint / newrpmMax
    showResult = Label (mGui, text=str(ResultCount)+". "+str(result)).pack()
    global ResultCount
    ResultCount +=1

    return

ResultCount = 1
mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('400x150+200+200')
mGui.title('RPM To Percent Calc')
rpmMaxSet = DoubleVar()
rpmMinSet = DoubleVar()
rpmPointSet = DoubleVar()
rpmMaxSetLabel = Label(mGui, text='Max RPM').pack()
rpmMaxSetEntry = Entry(textvariable=rpmMaxSet) .pack()
rpmMinSetLabel = Label(mGui, text='Min RPM').pack()
rpmMinSetEntry = Entry(textvariable=rpmMinSet) .pack()
rpmMinPointLabel = Label(mGui, text='Point RPM').pack()
rpmPointSetEntry = Entry(textvariable=rpmPointSet) .pack()

mButton = Button(mGui, text='Calculate', command = CalcRpmRatio, fg = 'white', bg='black').pack()
mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually, only last line is the problem. Other lines are totally OK.

Comment: @Lafexlos what about this statment     newrpmMax = rpmMax() - rpmMin() he is calling variables as function

Comment: Try it and you'll see it works perfectly. You can assign a function's definition to a variable and call it later. I'm not saying it is the ideal way to get the value like that in this particular example just saying _the_ problem of this question is only in the last line.

Comment: Okkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk accepted!